# Is there any reason the <use> tag in HTML renders an svg in different dimension of height and width?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an SVG element and I want to use it in many places so I used use tag .The use tag inside a SVG tag renders the svg in smaller dimension of height and width i.e. I asked for 20x20 dimension and it renders in 17x17.

`<svg id='polyline' height='210' width='400'><path d='M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z' /></svg>`

```html
<svg id='graph' width="12cm" height="5.25cm" viewBox="0 0 1200 400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">


  <path d="M300,200 h-150 a150,150 0 1,0 150,-150 z"
        fill="red" stroke="blue" stroke-width="5" />
  <path d="M275,175 v-150 a150,150 0 0,0 -150,150 z"
        fill="yellow" stroke="blue" stroke-width="5" />

</svg>

<p>I have got 54 x 54 image instead of 100 x 200<p>
<svg>
        <use href='#graph' height='100' width='200'></use>
      </svg>
<p>I have got 5 x 5 image instead of 20 x 20<p>
<svg>
        <use href='#graph' height='20' width='20'></use>
      </svg>
```

> height 100 x width 200

`<svg><use href='#polyline' height='100' width='200'></use></svg>`

> height 30 x width 30

`<svg><use href='#polyline' height='30' width='30'></use></svg>`

This in turn provides me with a Triangle svg with smaller height and width not the required one ,is this because of viewbox? or how can I obtain the required height and width.

Comment: In order to use width and height for the <use> element **1**. put both paths inside a symbol with a viewBox attribute. In this case please try `viewBox="125 25 325 325"`. **2**. use the symbol

Comment: @enxaneta Can you explain viewBox="125 25 325 325" this in brief.

Comment: It represents the bounding box of the two paths taken together. In order to know the bounding box you can use the getBBox() method on a group wrapping the two paths. In the example above the bounding box x = 125, y = 25, width = 325 and height = 325

Comment: Say if I have many SVGs will I have to perform this method for each of them to find their respective viewBox @enxaneta ..or do we have any other methods to do that

Comment: As explained by enxaneta you can get a tight viewBox via natively supported JavaScript method `getBBox()`. There is no way to do this in CSS alone as SVGs layout model doesn't support something like block elements or layout concept like flex or grid to distribute elements e.g. centering elements within the parent svg. Besides you can't control the `viewBox` settings via CSS. If you only have to fix a few svgs you can also open your files in an editor like inkscape and shrink the artboard/document size and save the file again.

Comment: Is there any other way that I could use inside a JSDOM to find the viewbox other than getBBox()? @enxaneta

Comment: Please take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62779904/get-the-bounding-box-of-the-intersection-of-2-or-more-paths#answer-63203972

Answer (score -3):

The  tag in HTML is used to embed and reuse SVG graphics within a document. When you use the  tag to reference an SVG, there can be differences in the rendering dimensions of the referenced SVG and the dimensions specified in the  tag. This is because the  tag allows you to reference a specific portion of an SVG and apply it at a different scale or position.

### Basic Syntax of :

```
<svg>
  <use xlink:href="#symbolId" width="desiredWidth" height="desiredHeight"></use>
</svg>
```

The xlink:href attribute refers to the ID of the original SVG element you want to reuse. You can specify the width and height attributes to control the size of the rendered SVG.

### Scaling and Transformations:

The  tag allows you to apply transformations, such as scaling, to the referenced SVG. If the original SVG has a different size, these transformations may result in different rendering dimensions.

```
<svg>
  <use xlink:href="#symbolId" width="100" height="50" transform="scale(2)"></use>
</svg>
```

### Viewport and Coordinate Systems:

The viewport and coordinate systems of the original SVG and the  context may differ, leading to variations in rendering dimensions.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 50">
  <use xlink:href="#symbolId" width="50" height="25"></use>
</svg>
```

### Aspect Ratio Preservation:

The  tag preserves the aspect ratio of the referenced SVG. If you specify only one dimension (width or height), the other dimension is automatically adjusted to maintain the original aspect ratio.

```
<svg>
  <use xlink:href="#symbolId" width="100"></use>
</svg>
```

### No Dimension Specified:

If you don't specify dimensions in the  tag, the rendering dimensions are inherited from the referenced SVG.

```
<svg>
  <use xlink:href="#symbolId"></use>
</svg>
```

## Summary

the  tag in HTML allows for the reuse of SVG graphics with the flexibility to control dimensions and apply transformations. However, understanding how these dimensions are determined and how transformations affect them is crucial for achieving the desired rendering outcome.

Comment: Hey, thanks and would like to add my points in here.  I've observed that the specified height and width aren't applying as intended. Any suggestions to address this?